# BSOD Error Code Explanation

Tags: windows, hex, error-code, bsod

I am retrieving system failure information from the event logs for diagnosis of system crash and displaying a list of possible issues.

In a generic BSOD, what do the four hex values in brackets signify. Is there anyway they can be used for further diagnosis of the problem, beyond the main error code? i.e `0x000000A`. If yes, how?

[image: BSOD]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I analyse a BSOD and the error information it will provide me?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321029/how-do-i-analyse-a-bsod-and-the-error-information-it-will-provide-me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first number is a [bug check code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh994433(v=vs.85).aspx).

The following numbers will be whatever the driver passed to [KeBugCheckEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551961(v=vs.85).aspx), so they're only really useful if you have the driver source code.

Comment: Is there any way I can identify the faulty driver by examining the other hex numbers? Or are they all driver-specific?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the steps mentioned in that answer.